# ubuntu 19.04 hangs on show Plymouth boot screen when installing

Tags: boot, screen, plymouth

I know this is a recurring question but maybe slightly different. On the test computer in question (2009 Toshiba Satellite 3GB RAM 160 GB ROM AMD Semperon) I had Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed first time no problems. I then tried to upgrade to 18.10, this is when things went wrong. It crashed half way through and would not properly boot back into 18.04, so I thought OK lets go back and do a fresh install of 18.04 as that worked before and it did not work. As it stands at the moment the only Distro I have been able to install is Solus which, to the best of my knowledge doesn't use Plymouth which is where my problems stem from, I think, as I am new to Ubuntu (linux in general) I of course may be totally wrong. Please help as I have run out of ideas. Sorry should mention, 19.04 is the version I am currently trying to install. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying the installation from USB, when you get to the screen shown below there's a couple of things you can try:

1. Press <kbd>F6</kbd>, and select `nomodeset` as shown in the image.  This may be enough by itself.
2. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and your cursor should be in "Boot Options".  Two of the options are "Quiet" and "Splash"

   - Splash displays the little dancing dots that just let you know your computer is running
   - Quiet hides system messages during boot
3. Remove both "quiet" and "splash"
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue the boot process

`nomodeset` delays the loading of video drivers until X is up and running, which assist in installation on some video cards.  Displaying the system messages while booting allows you to see if there are perhaps some warnings or errors that occur during the boot process.

[image]

Comment: Fixed. Thanks to Charles for helping navigate to where the real issue was. I followed the steps to the letter and it still didn't work, after getting to the boot options, I went to the beginning of the line to find that for some strange reason it was looking for a cdrom drive instead of USB, even though I changed the boot order in bios. I replaced cdrom with USB and it worked like a dream. I am not going to mark this as the correct answer because it may be an unusual issue. But could help someone with the same issue.