# Ubuntu 18.04 booting hangs on booting with a last message as "Starting show Plymouth Boot Screen...."

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, kernel, plymouth

As shown in the picture the booting of Ubuntu is frozen in this screen,I'm not even able to boot in recovery mode.

I have tried to install a new Ubuntu 18.04 with both a live USB and CD/DVD but even that freezes with a beaver wallpaper and nothing happens(i.e 18.04 default wallpaper of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I hope I get some help regarding this issue.

PS: I have a dual boot (win7 + ubuntu 18.04 , win7 works fine).

[image: As shown in the picture the booting of Ubuntu is frozen in this screen]

Comment: What type of hardware is this? Is it a desktop, laptop, what kind of CPU is it, and do you have anything else in your computer besides a CPU and ram like pcie cards?

Comment: It's a desktop with no extra cards attached.

Comment: And what is your CPU? Do you have dedicated graphic card?

Comment: no dedicated graphic card its an intel core i5-2400

Comment: Have you tried to boot with `nomodeset` as [shown here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139989/ubuntu-19-04-hangs-on-show-plymouth-boot-screen-when-installing/1139998#1139998)?

Comment: Yes, I did try nothing changed